# Working on Same file in GIthub

Tags: git, github

Currently me and my friend working on one web application, we both have perform push and pull operation in GitHub.

Now my question is, if I am working in file `test.php` and my friend also working in same file, once I finished my work, I create a new branch in GitHub and push into that branch and merge with `master`:  `master` now have the changes that I did.

My friend didn't have that changes, now how we will merge those two files, without affecting my changed that I did past?

We push and pull via terminal only and we didn't maintain any local repository also.

Comment: There is always a local repo. And since you push and pull, you're doing merges. Just read on how git works, github itself doesn't change anything.

Comment: so , we both must have to maintain local repo right , that's ok ,can you please explain little bit more..

Comment: You don't specifically have to but with git there always is one. You can't really have source control with git without having a repository on your machine.

Comment: This will be useful: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Thank you for your reply..Sami Kuhmonen

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: with github, it's not necessarily true (the local repo). One can edit files in the web ui!

Comment: ok sami , but we are changing group of files not a single file.

Comment: That's irrelevant, a commit can touch a single file or every one. Please cover the introductory material and, if you ask a question again, find someone to help you proof read it per [ask].

Comment: @Sergio: yes, and you can write the git protocol by hand and... But in real life you can't really do much without having the code locally.

Comment: Currently we are following these steps 1 ) Clone Master 2 ) Remove all files from Master 3 ) copy all files from my working folder ( ex www ) 4 ) git add . 5 ) git commit 6 ) Create a new branch and push into it 7 ) Merge into Master.In that in which step i have to change..

Comment: @Maheshwaran.S: "in which step i have to change" - all of them. You have to change your entire workflow. This is not how you work with git.

Answer (score 5):

> now master have the changes that i did , now my friend didn't have that changes , now how we will merge that two files , without affecting my changed that i did past

If he develop in his own branch, all he has to do is:

```
git fetch
git rebase master
# resolve conflicts
git push --force
```

The rebase part will replay his branch commits on top of the updated `master`, making sure his modifications are still compatible with `master` branch.
Later, his branch will be merged to master very easily (fast-forward merge, as said branch will always be additional commits on top of master because of the rebase)

See as an example "[Simple Git workflow is simple](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/01/simple-git-workflow-simple/) ", which involve a rebase:

[image: http://atlassian.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/rebase-on-feature.gif]

Comment: Thank you so much that's what i am expecting.

Comment: @Maheshwaran.S I have edited the answer to illustrate the rebase and point to an article detailling the workflow I recommend.

Comment: @Maheshwaran.S Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for this or your past questions.